# Sending Auth Token back to client spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am totally new to Springs and have been given a spring web project to analyse the authentication code been implemented there. I have understood most of the part but stuck in one place.
The project has a custom filter which authenticates via our custom provider and then sets this value in SecurityContextHolder.getContext().set...
The client uses the same token for further requests..
But I can not see anywhere how this value is being passed back to the client.
Can anyone tell me how it is done. Does internal implementation of spring classes send this in HttpServletResponse and if yes then how i.e. by setting headers or cookies etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token isn't sent back to the client. It's a server artifact which is stored in the server session. The only token between the client and the server is the standard `JSESSIONID` cookie which links the user to the session containing the authentication object on the server side.